# Centering game cards to middle (horizontally)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let cards = [];
let cardElements = [];
let flippedCards = [];
let matchedCards = [];
let tries = 0;

function startGame(numCards) {
  document.getElementById("start-screen").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("game-container").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("game-board").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("tries-counter").innerText = "Tries: 0";
  tries = 0;

  cards = [];
  let icons = [
    "yin-yang",
    "anchor",
    "baby",
    "bicycle",
    "wifi",
    "user-graduate",
    "truck-monster",
    "tablet-alt",
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < numCards / 2; i++) {
    cards.push(icons[i]);
    cards.push(icons[i]);
  }
  createCards();
}

function createCards() {
  let gameBoard = document.getElementById("game-board");
  gameBoard.innerHTML = "";
  cardElements = [];
  flippedCards = [];
  matchedCards = [];
  cards.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.dataset.value = cards[i];
    card.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
    gameBoard.appendChild(card);
    cardElements.push(card);
  }
}

function flipCard() {
  if (flippedCards.length === 2 || this === flippedCards[0]) return;
  this.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-${this.dataset.value}"></i>`;
  flippedCards.push(this);
  if (flippedCards.length === 2) {
    tries++;
    document.getElementById("tries-counter").innerText = `Tries: ${tries}`;
    setTimeout(checkForMatch, 1000);
  }
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = flippedCards[0].dataset.value === flippedCards[1].dataset.value;
  if (isMatch) {
    flippedCards.forEach((card) => card.classList.add("matched"));
    matchedCards = matchedCards.concat(flippedCards);
  } else {
    flippedCards.forEach((card) => {
      card.innerHTML = "";
    });
  }
  flippedCards = [];
  if (matchedCards.length === cardElements.length)
    toastr["success"](
      "You won in " + tries + " tries! Refresh the page to play again!"
    );
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100vw;
}

#game-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
}

#game-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  place-self: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.card {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.matched {
  background-color: #0f0 !important;
}

#tries-counter {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

button {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#start-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Memory Card Game</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toastr.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="start-screen">
      <h1>Select card game size</h1>
      <div>
        <button onclick="startGame(4)">4</button>
        <button onclick="startGame(6)">6</button>
        <button onclick="startGame(8)">8</button>
        <button onclick="startGame(10)">10</button>
        <button onclick="startGame(12)">12</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="game-container" style="display: none">
      <div id="tries-counter">Tries: 0</div>
      <div id="game-board"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) please

Comment: @Suleyman updated op with fiddle

Comment: @JordanThompson I believe Suleyman was speaking of a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/), which makes the code runnable on *this* site. Since you already had the code here, it's just a matter of editing your question, clicking the button that looks like `<>`, and adding the appropriate code to the three quadrants. Please do this yourself on future HTML/CSS/JS questions.

Comment: Updated, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

### Align cards in the start screen

Add a div wrapper to the buttons, like:

```html
<div id="start-screen">
      <h1>Select card game size</h1>
      <div id="buttons">
          <button onclick="startGame(4)">4</button>
          <button onclick="startGame(6)">6</button>
          <button onclick="startGame(8)">8</button>
          <button onclick="startGame(10)">10</button>
          <button onclick="startGame(12)">12</button>
      </div>
      ...
</div>
```

Then, add this CSS rule:

```css
#start-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

### Align cards in the game container

Change the JS code from `grid` to `flex`;

```js
// Change grid
document.getElementById("game-board").style.display = "grid";

// To flex
document.getElementById("game-board").style.display = "flex";
```

To fix card size on smaller screens, replace the `#game-board` rule to this:

```css
#game-board {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    max-width: 90vw;
    max-height: 90vh;
}
```

### Flex vs Grid

Flex and Grid are two different [layout modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_mode). You might be able to create layouts with both of them, but [they have huge differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Relationship_of_grid_layout_with_other_layout_methods#grid_and_flexbox) that, depending on the scenario, makes one a better choice than the other. In this case, the problem could be easily solved with flex.

Comment: That _does_ fix the alignment issue, but on smaller screen sizes it brings the cards smaller (https://imgur.com/a/2jTQmWZ).

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix card size on smaller screens:)

Comment: Thank you for the update :). That does fix the issue there, now the cards on board size 6 and up overflow to the right, is there a way to get it to break on smaller screens?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird because the declaration `flex-wrap: wrap;` should do the job, can upload an updated version of your snippet?

Comment: nvm, `max-height: 90vh` might be the problem. Delete that declaration and see if thats what you expect

Comment: I've updated the code in the OP, that didn't seem to work.